# How to generate an ID from the content first letter sequences in xslt?

Tags: xslt

I need to generate a Sequence id for TOC part and idref for the referenced places using the content first three letters.

Input:

```
<tocentry><title>List of Boxed Readings</title></tocentry>
<tocentry><title>Foreword</title></tocentry>
<tocentry><title>About the Author</title></tocentry>
<tocentry><title>Preface</title></tocentry>
<tocentry><title>A Dinosaur Dictionary</title></tocentry>
<tocentry><title>GLOSSARY</title></tocentry>
<tocentry><title>INDEX</title></tocentry>
```

Required OUtput:

```
<p class="Toc-part"><a href="#LOBRSec1">List of Boxed Readings</a></p>
<p class="Toc-part"><a href="#ForeSec2">Foreword</a></p>
<p class="Toc-part"><a href="#AtASec3">About the Author</a></p>
<p class="Toc-part"><a href="#PrefSec4">Preface</a></p>
<p class="Toc-part"><a href="#ADDSec5">A Dinosaur Dictionary</a></p>
<p class="Toc-part"><a href="#GLOSSec6">GLOSSARY</a></p>
<p class="Toc-part"><a href="#INDXSec7">INDEX</a></p>
```

Please help me to generate ID from the content first letters...

Best regards,
Antony

Comment: Why do you want a potentially ambiguous letter combination *and* an unambiguous counter in the same ID. From what I can see, calling the sections "`Sec1..SecN`" is enough, while calling them "`LOBRSec1`" buys you nothing while causing a hell of a lot extra work.

Comment: These portions are part titles, i have already given "sect1 to secN.. for the chapter titles and section titles.. so frontmatter titles needs to be sequenced by their names first letter, this will help to give idref inside the chapter. Hope you get my requirement..! :)

Answer (score 1):

Since I can't see why you would want some arbitrary letter combination in an ID that already *is* unique, I dis-recommend that and say you go with this instead:

```
<xsl:template match="tocentry">
  <p class="Toc-part">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="title" />
  </p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="title">
  <a href="#Sec{count(preceding-sibling::title) + 1}">
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
  </a>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

**This problem will never be solved, because it is not formulated correctly**. You do not present strict rules for producing the Ids -- for example, why INDX but not INDE ? Why ATA and not ATAU?

**This problem has an ellegant solution**, put into XSLT by the designers of the language. Do read about the [**`generate-id()`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#function-generate-id) function and use it to generate your ids.

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard word instead of the content in the id

for example if it is frontmatter use "FMSec1, FMSec2, FMSec3..... FMSecN.."

"FM" will be the difference than others...